# Is there something I can change in my code?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ALTER TABLE `ecommerce`.`users` ADD id INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

This is my SQL code. When I run it I get

> #1060 duplicate column name 'id'

Kindly help

Comment: You can't add a column that already exists. Maybe remove it first? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I accepted the answer as the code worked. Thanks

Comment: @forpas Thank you for your answer, I just realized that I can accept only one answer. Sorry about that. Kindly excuse. I had accepted your answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that there is already a column with the name `id` in your table, so you can't add another one with the same name.

What you can do is modify the existing column's attributes:

```
ALTER TABLE `ecommerce`.`users` MODIFY COLUMN id INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

If the existing column is not already set as `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` you must also set one of these in the `ALTER` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `ecommerce`.`users` MODIFY COLUMN id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update existing column as below

```
ALTER TABLE `ecommerce`.`users` MODIFY COLUMN id INT auto_increment
```